# replace all lines which contain a certain word with a new word in all PHP files in a folder

Tags: php, linux, sed

Assume I have a folder with many php files in it, and some of those php files have a line that has a specific word, i need a linux command line which find all files which have that lines(which contains a specific word) and replace that lines with another word
for example:

```
     $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
     $target = "upload/".$_FILES['fupload']['name'];
     move_uploaded_file( $source, $target );// or die ("Couldn't copy");
     $size = getImageSize( $target );
```

in above code which is part of a php file, assume that specific word is "fupload" and we want replace that line with "echo" after running linux command line it becomes this one:

```
     echo
     $target = "upload/".$_FILES['fupload']['name'];
     move_uploaded_file( $source, $target );// or die ("Couldn't copy");
     $size = getImageSize( $target );
```

and this process executes for all phph files which have this situation.

I found this code but this code only removes lines which contains specific word but I need to replace whole of those lines with another word:

```
      find /var/www/website -type f -exec sed -i '/$vjfegamd/d' {} ';'
```

Comment: You want to replace every instance of `fupload` because technically `$target` should be replaced too?

Comment: What if `fuploaded` appeared in your input - would that line be replaced too? Can the "word" you are looking for contain regexp metacharacters or not? Can it contain non-alphabetic characters (and if so how do you define a "word")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace only the first occurence of `fupload`(as in your sample code), try this:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 -exec sed -i.bak '0,/fupload/c echo' {} \;
```

The `c` command changes the whole line with the string following the command.

Before editing, all files are saved with a `.bak` extension.

As some sed flavors require `c` to be followed with a new line, you can try this one for the same result:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 -exec sed i.bak '0,/fupload/s//echo/' {} \;
```